# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in */prestashop/src/PrestaShopBundle/Translation/Loader/SqlTranslationLoader.php on line 103

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to update Prestashop from 1.6 to 1.7.4.3 and I get the following error:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/*/prestashop/src/PrestaShopBundle/Translation/Loader/SqlTranslationLoader.php on line 103

The code on these line is:

```
/**
 * @param $translations
 * @param $catalogue
 */
protected function addTranslationsToCatalogue($translations, MessageCatalogueInterface $catalogue)
{
    foreach ($translations as $translation) {
        $catalogue->set($translation['key'], $translation['translation'], $translation['domain']);
    }
}
```

}

But it is the default code from the prestashop installation, i didn't any change on it.

Please, I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have write privileges to the `/var` and `/translations` folders.